# Loop through Array and count

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

Been struggling with counting through this array. I was able to do it previously but I don't think I quite understand how the parameters of a function are assigned its data.

I am bringing in an array with from JSON data over AJAX, then using a `.each` loop to go through the data and count it. But I can't seem to count it when using the index parameter. It is just giving me the actual objects and not counting how many objects there are.

I was hoping that someone could help me understand why I am getting the object and not the count of objects in the array. What I have now is just my final attempt at getting it to count, I know it's wrong.

I am trying to count how many "results" there are in the array (that came from the JSON file).

I have added snippets of my code and attached a link to the JSON file. I have also marked the problem area with a comment saying ***Problem Area***

CODE -

```js
$.getJSON('http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=ZAR', {
        action: "query", 
        list: "search",
        format: "json",
}
        , function (data) {
            var baseCurr = data.base;
            var baseDate = data.date;
            $('#curr-cont').append('<div class="base row1" id="row1"><div class="base flag" id="flag"><i class="famfamfam-flag-za"></i></div><div class="base country-name"><p class="c-name" id="count-name">' + baseCurr + '</p></div><div class="base currency"><p class="c-amount" id="curr">' + baseDate + '</p></div></div>');

           //***Problem Area***
    
            var rates = [data];
    
            $.each(rates[0], function (i, obj) {
               console.log(obj); 
            });

            $.each(data.rates, function (i, item) {
                var amount = [item];
                var name = [i];
                var maxLength = 4;
                var string = amount.toString();
                string = string.substr(0, maxLength);
                // amount = amount.substr(0, maxLength);
                
                $('#curr-cont').append('<div class="row1" id="row1"><div class="flag" id="flag"><i class="famfamfam-flag-' + name + '"></i></div><div class="country-name"><p class="c-name" id="count-name">' + name + '</p></div><div class="currency"><p class="c-amount" id="curr">' + string + '</p></div></div>');
                
//                if(i > 0){
//                    $('#list1').append('<li>' + name + '</li>');
//                }
//                else{
//                    $('#list2').append('<li>' + name + '</li>');
//                }
                
                
            });
    
    });
```

[JSON Data File](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00394814274663352909)

Comment: I don't see you counting anything in that code, where would you assume the counting to happen?

Comment: Yes that's the problem. I am trying to count the amount of rates there are in the JSON file.

Comment: If it's truly and Array then use https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp . If it's an Object then use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: http://jsbin.com/semuhecube/edit?js,console,output

Comment: I see that that works, but in that format.. How would I create the str variable with the getJSON at the top?

Comment: I keep getting - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit:**
since rates is an object and not an array, you can do: `Object.keys(data.rates).length`.

`Object.keys(...)` will give you an array with all the keys in the object.

**original:**

If you want to know the number of rates in that file: `data.rates.length` will give you the length of the rates `Array` that is returned in the data.
No need to count it

Comment: Thank you for your help. You were right! Appreciate it :)